# How do you install Civ 5 without using heaps of download?

Tags: civilization-5

I bought the CD of Civilization 5 and when I tried installing it, it says it has to download 2.8 GB from Steam. How do I avoid this and just download directly of the disc?

Comment: Civ 5 has been updated a lot since release, that's probably a lot of the download.

Comment: If you have DLC, it adds up to even more. Civ V currently takes up more than 8GB for me, with Gold Edition (Gods and Kings with scenarios) and Brave New World.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The **base install** is covered by the CD contents.

The game will need to download **extra** update data from steam though (E.g: patches, updates or any compatibility updates for any DLC, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

[Via "Installing from Disc instead of Steam"](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=5357-FSQM-0382):

1. Log in to Steam and click on Library
2. Right-click on the game, select Delete local content, and confirm (note: if not visible, ignore and proceed to next step)
3. Insert the first disc into your computer
4. Close Steam (Steam > Exit)
5. Press Windows Key + R to open Run
6. In the Run window type (note: Replace E: with the CD/DVD drive you are installing from if is not correct, and replace C:\Program Files\Steam if your Steam installation is not in the default location):

   "C:\Program Files\Steam\Steam.exe" -install E:
7. Press OK

Steam will launch and ask you to sign in if you do not have your password saved.  Your installation should continue from the disc.

As mentioned in another answer, you will likely still have to download additional patches, updates, and so forth. Hopefully this saves some time.